# Qual a formula usada para calcular FPS em um jogo?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Estou criando um jogo em java usando a lwjgl3, já vi muitos algoritmos mas todos são diferentes um do outro.

Então simplificando meu código seria como esse:

```
start();

while(running){
    update();
    render();
}

exit();
```

Qual formula eu poderia usar para calcular os fps do jogo?

Comment: Isso resolve https://tutorialedge.net/lwjgl-3-fps-main-game-loop ? Eu não vou formular uma resposta porque não entendo de lwjgl, mas se vc testar você mesmo pode responder a sua propria pergunta :)

Comment: Pesquise algo chamado Simple Moving Average - SMA. Segundo o site OANDA: "SMA significa simple moving average (média móvel simples). Ajuda a suavizar a curva de preços para uma melhor identificação da tendência. Quanto maior o período da SMA seleccionado, mais suave a curva". Obviamente, troque "preços" aí por "frames por segundo". :) Também não vou colocar uma resposta pelo mesmo motivo do Guilherme.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento era isso que eu estava procurando, pois eu só encontrava tutoriais sobre a lwjgl 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A taxa de quadros por segundo (FPS ou QPS) pode ser calculada da seguinte maneira:

```
public void start() {
    lastFPS = getTime();
}

public void updateFPS() {
    if (getTime() - lastFPS > 1000) {
        Display.setTitle("FPS: " + fps); 
        fps = 0; //reseta o contador de FPS
        lastFPS += 1000; //adiciona um segundo
    }
    fps++;
}
```

A representação de FPS é simples, são quantos quadros foram exibidos em um único segundo. A taxa de quadros por segundo ser 30, significa que em um segundo, foram exibidos 30 quadros.

A fórmula, numa representação básica, seria: **FPS = (quantidade de quadros) / (quantidade de segundos)**.  Por exemplo, se em 
120 segundos foram exibidos 6400 quadros, nosso FPS seria ± 53,333 (6400 / 120).

O `Display.setTitle(String title)` é para simplificar, mostrando o contador no título da janela.

Mais informações na [documentação](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/LWJGL_Basics_4_(Timing).html#Calculating_FPS).